# Callout on top of UITextView like in iMessage

Tags: ios, swift, message, callout

Is there an easy way without a custom view to achieve the Copy-More-Callyout on top of Message Bubbles like in iMessage?
Whatever I searched for didn't lead me to a solution.

My Bubble is based on a non-editable `UITextView`.

[image]